# Estimating drag due to wind - ribbon-shaped sail

Tags: aerodynamics, drag

In the countless calculations and discussions concerning the "space rope" I've never found any addressing its capability to resist winds.

Consider, as in most current works, it's a 1m wide ribbon, attached near equator, going straight up past geostationary orbit. It's being projected for 20 tons of load on top of its own weight. But never in the calculations did I see the drag put by [trade winds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_wind) typical to that area on what is essentially good several thousand meters of a sail.

This *will be* a considerable force. A ship of displacement of 400 tons, like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fryderyk_Chopin_%28ship%29) is capable of travel of 30km/hour against the drag of water with sail surface of 1200m^2. Of course it is projected to gather as much force with the sails as possible, but the tower will have at least an order of magnitude more of the "sail surface".

How would one go about calculating what lateral strength would be put on that tower by the wind (trade winds are up to 8m/s but I'm not sure if it's applicable for higher altitudes), on its part that is still immersed in atmosphere? 1m wide ribbon, going straight up, assuming pessimistic scenario of being oriented perpendicular to wind direction.

Comment: Remember jet stream winds can be over 50m/s, and they are unpredictable in their route. Admittedly the strongest ones are closer to the pole, but be aware of loops of high altitude (>30000m), high speed winds in any calculation.

Comment: Good question. I can imagine there could be technical solutions along the lines of how oscillations are addressed in airfoils and tall buildings.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Due to lower air density drag caused at these altitudes will be lower than of proportional low altitude winds. OTOH, the speeds may be significantly higher.

Comment: I'd be more concerned with the oscillations set up in the ribbon. All a constant drag force will do is displace the space elevator from the true vertical (and I think it's not exactly vertical to begin with). The oscillations induced by the wind, though, will travel in waves up and down the whole cable, if not damped somehow.

Comment: @Christoph: Displace enough of it from true vertical - pull it down far enough - and you pull it off balance and it falls down.

Comment: you have to pull it far enough to move the heavy mass that's probably at the end of the tether (65000km away) inside the point of equilibrium. if you deflect it to 45° over the whole atmosphere, this would only mean about 40km more ribbon. I kind of doubt that the designers would not accomodate for this - if you build a tether 65000km long, you might as well make it a bit longer.

Comment: @Christoph: The tether doesn't need to reach 2x as far as the orbit. It only needs to stretch only a small way out beyond GEO and carry enough (proportionally more) of counter-balance there. Plus 45 degrees is pretty optimistic assessment: as lower part is pushed low to the ground, more of the "sail" is pulled from above the atmosphere and the ribbon carried by wind may stretch many, many thicknesses of the atmosphere along the surface... unless you put a counter-balance heavy enough - heavy enough to overcome strength of the wind I wrote about!

Comment: sorry, that was a mixup 36/63000km.

Comment: @SF: OK, I found a paper about this. see my answer for more details, that won't fit in the comment field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat unsurprisingly, someone already has written a paper about this: [Approximating Aerodynamic Response of the Space Elevator to Lower Atmospheric Wind](http://home.comcast.net/~GTOSS/Paper_10152112Lang_Aero.pdf)
I have only skim-read it, but I think you should find a lot of information in there.

The most interesting tidbits: Max. horizontal deflection was about 200km for typhoon-strength winds (but only O(10km) for more normal conditions), some configurations lead to near-horizontal angles near the ground, and the presence of a climber has significant influence on the shape attained.

There's also an acompanying website, apparently: http://spaceelevatorwiki.com/wiki/index.php/Aerodynamic_Response

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate the drag equation vertically:
dF = 1/2*dA*Cd*rho(z)*v(z)^2.

dA = 1m^2/m = 1m in your example; dA is the width of the ribbon.
cD ~1.2 for a flat square plate going into the wind, for a long thin plate I am not sure exactly but it should be around 1.
Rho = density. It drops off by a factor of 2 every ~5000m and starts at 1.2kg/m^3.

Main assumptions:
1. High Re and low mean-free path: valid for all but the (unimportant) tenuous upper atmosphere.
2. The change in v and rho is gradual on the scale of the width, which is valid except for possibly a few points of extreme wind-shear (these exceptions won't add up to much, however).